# update $scope to specific field json ionic backand results in blank data in object && validate username password to field from backand

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, backend, backand

Im new to ionic + backand
there is 2 problem that occured

1-validation.username and password validation from backand(backend) field.(not authentication to connect backand api.

2.Update multiple input into field in backand database.There is no data available on backand but the id are incremented which mean exist in connection to back end but return no value at all.

Here is my form

```
<form ng-controller="shareJobCtrl" name="signForm" class="list">
        <div class="spacer" style="height: 100px;"></div>
        <ion-list>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                <input type="text" ng-model="password" placeholder="">
            </label>
        </ion-list>
        <a ng-click="addShare()"  style="font-weight:;" class="button button-stable  button-block">Sign up</a>
    </form>
```

**ShareJobCtrl**

```
.controller('shareJobCtrl', function($scope,Backand,shareservice,$state,$window) {

$scope.Share=[];
var baru = ({
                    "username": $scope.username,
                    "password": $scope.password
            });




 function getAllShare(){
 shareservice.getShare().then(function(result){
     $scope.Share = result.data.data;
 })
 }


  $scope.loginShare = function (){
    shareservice.get().then(function (results) {
        $scope.Share=results.data.data;
        console.log('Login', Share);
         }, function(error) {
       alert('Username is not valid');
        console.error(error);
    });

 }
 $scope.addShare = function(){
shareservice.addShare(baru).then(function(results){
    getAllShare();
    alert('Registration succesfull.Please login');
   $state.go('loginShareJob');      
   })};


 getAllShare();

})
```

**service.js**

```
.service('shareservice', function ($http, Backand){

 var baseUrl = '/1/objects/';
 var objectName = 'Share/';
 var obj=[];

  function getUrl(){
      return Backand.getApiUrl() + baseUrl + objectName;
  }

  function getUrlForId(){
      return getUrl() + Id;

  }

  getShare = function(){
      return $http.get(getUrl());
  };

  addShare = function (Share){
      return $http.post(getUrl(),Share);
  };


    loginShare = function () {
      return $http.get(getUrl())
    };


 return {
     getShare: getShare,
     addShare: addShare,
     loginShare: loginShare



}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

1. please follow backand docs for signup [here](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/apidescription/#sign-up), it has different url a parameters
2. make sure your fields json-name is correct, it sound like the user input do not map to backand fields